# Object reverting to Null when I call methods c++

Tags: c++, class, null, scope

I'm currently working a Rolodex for a class of mine. However, I seem to have problems calling its class methods. Whenever I try to call a method, lets take getCurrent() for example, it ends up passing an empty Rolodex object to call the function. When I debug it, it says that my current Rolodex object will call the method, but when I follow that method, inside the object is empty. Any suggestions?

Here is the snippet I'm looking at :

```
 if(!myRolodex.getCurrent() != 0) { // make sure its not empty
    string s1 = "Name", s2 = "Address", s3 = "Phone Number" , 
       s4 = "E-Mail", s5 = "Return to Menu";
```

Here is my header and source file for the Rolodex Class:

```
#include "Rolodex.h"

Rolodex::Rolodex() : current(0) {
}
Rolodex::Rolodex(const Rolodex& r) : current(r.current) {
for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LENGTH; i++)
    rdex[i] = r.rdex[i];
}

RolodexEntry Rolodex::get(long index) const {
if(index < MAX_LENGTH && index  >= 0)
    return rdex[index];
else {
    cout << "ERROR: Index is out of bounds." << endl;
    RolodexEntry entry;
    return entry;   // returns empty entry showing that it was unsuccessful
}//endelse
}

bool Rolodex::set(long index, const RolodexEntry& entry) {
if(index < MAX_LENGTH && index >= 0) {
    rdex[index] = entry;
}//endif
else
    return false;
}

bool Rolodex::add(const RolodexEntry& entry) {
if(!isfull()) {
    rdex[current] = entry;
    current++;
    return true;
}//endif
    return false;
}

bool Rolodex::remove(long index) {
if(index < MAX_LENGTH && index >= 0) {
    return rdex[index].erase();
}
}

void Rolodex::print_all(bool xml) {
 for(int i = 0; i < current; i++)   // cycle through all created entries
     if(!rdex[i].iserased())        // make sure it only prints valid entries
        rdex[i].print_entry(xml);   // print entry
}

RolodexEntry Rolodex::findEntry(string entry, long type) {
RolodexEntry anEntry; // empty entry
if(getCurrent() != 0) {
    string str;
    switch (type) { // pick how to search entry
        case 1: // name
            for(int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
                anEntry = get(i); // get current entry
                // string to represent full name
                str = anEntry.get_fname() + " " + anEntry.get_lname();
                if(findstr(str, entry) != -1) {
                    anEntry.print_entry(false);
                    cout << "Do you want this contact, or to continue searching?";
                    char input;
                    cin >> input;
                    input = tolower(input);
                    cin.ignore();
                    if(input == 'y')
                        return anEntry;
                } //endif
            }//endfor
            break;
        case 2: // address
            for(int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
                anEntry = get(i); // get current entry
                // string to represent full name
                str = anEntry.get_street() + " " + anEntry.get_town()
                        + anEntry.get_state() + " " + anEntry.get_zip();
                if(findstr(str, entry) != -1) {
                    anEntry.print_entry(false);
                    cout << "Do you want this contact, or to continue searching?";
                    char input;
                    cin >> input;
                    input = tolower(input);
                    cin.ignore();
                    if(input == 'y')
                        return anEntry;
                }//endif
            }//endfor
            break;
        case 3: // phone
            for(int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
                anEntry = get(i); // get current entry
                // string to represent full name
                str = anEntry.get_phone();
                if(findstr(str, entry) != -1) {
                    anEntry.print_entry(false);
                    cout << "Do you want this contact, or to continue searching?";
                    char input;
                    cin >> input;
                    input = tolower(input);
                    cin.ignore();
                    if(input == 'y')
                        return anEntry;
                }//endif
            }//endfor
            break;
        case 4: //email
            for(int i = 0; i < current; i++) {
                anEntry = get(i); // get current entry
                // string to represent full name
                str = anEntry.get_email();
                if(findstr(str, entry) != -1) {
                    anEntry.print_entry(false);
                    cout << "Do you want this contact, or to continue searching?";
                    char input;
                    cin >> input;
                    input = tolower(input);
                    cin.ignore();
                    if(input == 'y')
                        return anEntry;
                }//endif
            }//endfor
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Error: Invalid search choice." << endl;
            break;
    }; // endswitch
}//end if
else 
    cout << "Rolodex is empty" << endl;
return anEntry;
}

int Rolodex::findstr(string str, string sub) {
//turn string to lower case
transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), tolower);
transform(sub.begin(), sub.end(), sub.begin(), tolower);
size_t found = str.find(sub);
if(found != string::npos)
    return (int)found; // return index of where it starts
else
    return -1;
}
```

Here is my Rolodex header

```
#ifndef ROLODEX_H
#define ROLODEX_H

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include "RolodexEntry.h"

using namespace std;

const long MAX_LENGTH = 20;

class Rolodex {
private:
    RolodexEntry rdex[MAX_LENGTH];
    long current;
    int findstr(string str, string sub);

public:
    Rolodex();
    Rolodex(const Rolodex& r);

    bool isfull() const {return current == MAX_LENGTH;}
    long getCurrent() const {return current;};
    RolodexEntry get(long index) const;
    bool set(long index, const RolodexEntry& entry);
    bool add(const RolodexEntry& entry);
    bool remove(long index);
    void print_all(bool xml);
    bool isdeleted();
    RolodexEntry findEntry(string entry, long type);

};

#endif
```

And here is the source file I'm working on to drive my program:

```
#include "Rolodex.h"
#include "RolodexEntry.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

static void menu();
static void add();
static void edit();
static void removeEntry();
static void find();
static void print();
static void setInfo(RolodexEntry& r);
static void editEntry(RolodexEntry& r);

Rolodex myRolodex;

int main() {
menu();
}

static void menu() {
bool end = false;
string test1 = "Add Entry",
       test2 = "Edit Entry",
       test3 = "Remove Entry",
       test4 = "Find Entry",
       test5 = "Print All Entries",
       test6 = "Quit";

while(!end) {
    // print menu options
    cout << setw(5) << right << "1) " << test1 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "2) " << test2 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "3) " << test3 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "4) " << test4 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "5) " << test5 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "6) " << test6 << endl;

    // receive user input
    string input;
    cout << "\n> ";
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << endl;

    // menu options
    if(input == "1" || input == "A" || input == "a" || input == test1) 
        add();
    else if(input == "2" || input == "E" || input == "e" || input == test2)
        edit();
    else if(input == "3" || input == "R" || input == "r" || input == test3)
        removeEntry();
    else if(input == "4" || input == "F" || input == "f" || input == test4)
        find();
    else if(input == "5" || input == "P" || input == "p" || input == test5)
        print();
    else if(input == "6" || input == "Q" || input == "q" || input == test6)
        end = true;
    else
        cout << "Error: Invalid input." << endl;
}//endwhile
}


static void add() {
string string1 = "Add", string2 = "Return to Previous Menu";
cout << "1)" << string1 << endl;
cout << "2)" << string2 << endl;
cout << "\n> ";
string choice;
getline(cin, choice);

if(choice == "2"||choice == "R"|| choice == "r" || choice == string2)
    return; //user chose to return so quit

if(!myRolodex.isfull()) { // make sure rolodex is not full
    bool correct = false;
    RolodexEntry anEntry;   // create entry

    while(!correct) {   // makes sure user has the correct entry before its added
        // set all data for entry
        setInfo(anEntry);
        // print entry for user to authenticate
        cout << "\nIs this correct?" << endl;
        anEntry.print_entry(false);

        // take user input and determine whether or not to add entry
        cout << "\n>";  
        char input;
        cin >> input;
        input = tolower(input);
        if(input == 'y') {
            myRolodex.add(anEntry);     // add entry
            correct = true;
        }//endif
        else {
            cout << "Would you like to redo this entry?";
            cin >> input;
            input = tolower(input);
            if(input != 'y') {
                correct = true;
                cout << endl;
            }//endif
        }//endelse
        cin.ignore();
    }//endwhile
}//endif
else {  //rolodex is full, ask to overwrite
    cout << "Rolodex is full...Would you like to overwrite an existing entry? ";
    char over;
    cin >> over;
    tolower(over);
    cin.ignore();
    if(over == 'y') { // overwrite (similar to find but it doesn't print

        string s1 = "Name", s2 = "Address", s3 = "Phone Number" , 
                s4 = "E-Mail", s5 = "Return to Menu";
        string input, ifin;

        cout << "How would you like to search?" << endl << "1) " << s1 << endl;
        cout << "2) " << s2 << endl;
        cout << "3) " << s3 << endl;
        cout << "4) " << s4 << endl;
        cout << "5) " << s5 << endl;
        cout << "\n> ";
        RolodexEntry anEntry;
        getline(cin, input);

        /* match input with option
           print
           get input
           find specified entry
           set info for entry
        */
        if(input == "1" || input == "N" || input == "n" || input == s1) {
            cout << "Enter first or last name only: ";
            getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 1);
            setInfo(anEntry);
        }
        if(input == "2" || input == "A" || input == "a" ||  input == s2)  {
            cout << "Enter street name only: ";
            getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 2);
            setInfo(anEntry);
        }
        if(input == "3" || input == "P" || input == "p" ||  input == s3)  {
            cout << "Enter phone number: ";
            getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 3);
            setInfo(anEntry);
        }
        if(input == "4" || input == "E" || input == "e" ||  input == s4)  {
            cout << "Enter email: ";
            getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 4);
            setInfo(anEntry);
        }
        if(input == "5" || input == "R" || input == "r" ||  input == s5) 
            return;
    }
}
}

static void edit() {
if(!myRolodex.getCurrent() != 0) {  // make sure its not empty
    string s1 = "Name", s2 = "Address", s3 = "Phone Number" , 
       s4 = "E-Mail", s5 = "Return to Menu";

    cout << "Find entry by..." << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "1) " << s1 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "2) " << s2 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "3) " << s3 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "4) " << s4 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "5) " << s5 << endl;

    string input, ifin;
    cout << "\n> ";
    RolodexEntry anEntry;
    getline(cin, input);

    /* match input with option
           print
           get input
           find specified entry
           edit info for entry
    */
    if(input == "1" || input == "N" || input == "n" || input == s1) {
        cout << "Enter first or last name only: ";
        getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 1);
        editEntry(anEntry);
    }
    if(input == "2" || input == "A" || input == "a" ||  input == s2)  {
        cout << "Enter street name only: ";
        getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 2);
        editEntry(anEntry);
    }
    if(input == "3" || input == "P" || input == "p" ||  input == s3)  {
        cout << "Enter phone number: ";
        getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 3);
        editEntry(anEntry);
    }
    if(input == "4" || input == "E" || input == "e" ||  input == s4)  {
        cout << "Enter email: ";
        getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 4);
        editEntry(anEntry);
    }
    if(input == "5" || input == "R" || input == "r" ||  input == s5) 
        return;
}//endif
else
    cout << "Rolodex is empty" << endl;
}

static void removeEntry() {
string s1 = "Name", s2 = "Address", s3 = "Phone Number" , 
       s4 = "E-Mail", s5 = "Return to Menu";

cout << "Find Entry By..." << endl;
cout << setw(5) << right << "1) " << s1 << endl;
cout << setw(5) << right << "2) " << s2 << endl;
cout << setw(5) << right << "3) " << s3 << endl;
cout << setw(5) << right << "4) " << s4 << endl;
cout << setw(5) << right << "5) " << s5 << endl;

string input, ifin;
cout << "\n> ";
RolodexEntry anEntry;
getline(cin, input);

/* match input with option
      print
      get input
      find specified entry
      remove entry
*/
if(input == "1" || input == "N" || input == "n" || input == s1) {
    cout << "Enter first or last name only: ";
    getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 1);
    anEntry.erase();
}
if(input == "2" || input == "A" || input == "a" ||  input == s2)  {
    cout << "Enter street name only: ";
    getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 2);
    anEntry.erase();
}
if(input == "3" || input == "P" || input == "p" ||  input == s3)  {
    cout << "Enter phone number: ";
    getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 3);
    anEntry.erase();
}
if(input == "4" || input == "E" || input == "e" ||  input == s4)  {
    cout << "Enter email: ";
    getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 4);
    anEntry.erase();
}
if(input == "5" || input == "R" || input == "r" ||  input == s5) 
    return;
}

static void find() {
if(!myRolodex.getCurrent() != 0) {  // not emtpy
    string s1 = "Name", s2 = "Address", s3 = "Phone Number" , 
           s4 = "E-Mail", s5 = "Return to Menu";

    cout << "How would you like to search?" << endl << "1) " << s1 << endl;
            cout << "2) " << s2 << endl;
            cout << "3) " << s3 << endl;
            cout << "4) " << s4 << endl;
            cout << "5) " << s5 << endl;

    string input, ifin;
    cout << "\n> ";
    RolodexEntry anEntry;
    getline(cin, input);

    /* match input with option
          print
          get input
          find specified entry
          print entry
    */
    if(input == "1" || input == "N" || input == "n" || input == s1) {
        cout << "Enter first or last name only: ";
        getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 1);
        anEntry.print_entry(false);
    }
    if(input == "2" || input == "A" || input == "a" ||  input == s2)  {
        cout << "Enter street name only: ";
        getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 2);
        anEntry.print_entry(false);
    }
    if(input == "3" || input == "P" || input == "p" ||  input == s3)  {
        cout << "Enter phone number: ";
        getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 3);
        anEntry.print_entry(false);
    }
    if(input == "4" || input == "E" || input == "e" ||  input == s4)  {
        cout << "Enter email: ";
        getline(cin, ifin);
            anEntry = myRolodex.findEntry(ifin, 4);
        anEntry.print_entry(false);
    }
    if(input == "5" || input == "R" || input == "r" ||  input == s5) 
        return;
}//endif
}

static void print() {
if(!myRolodex.getCurrent() != 0) { //check if empty
    string c1 = "Print", c2 = "Print XML Tags", c3 = "Return to menu";
    // print menu options
    cout << setw(5) << right << "1) " << c1 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "2) " << c2 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "3) " << c3 << endl;

    // receive user input
    string input;
    cout << "\n> ";
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << endl;

    // menu options
    if(input == "1" || input == "P" || input == "p" || input == c1) 
        myRolodex.print_all(false);
    else if(input == "2" || input == "X" || input == "x" || input == c2)
        myRolodex.print_all(true);
    else if(input == "3" || input == "R" || input == "r" || input == c3)
        return;
    else
        cout << "Error: Invalid input." << endl;
}//endif
else
    cout << "Rolodex is empty" << endl;
}

static void setInfo(RolodexEntry& r) {
string fname,
       lname,
       street,
       town,
       state,
       phone,
       email,
       zip;

cout << "First Name: ";
getline(cin, fname); 
r.set_fname(fname);

cout << "Last Name: ";
getline(cin, lname); 
r.set_lname(lname);

cout << "Street Name: ";
getline(cin, street); 
r.set_street(street);

cout << "Town Name: ";
getline(cin, town); 
r.set_town(town);

cout << "State Name: ";
getline(cin, state); 
r.set_state(state);

cout << "Zip-Code: ";
getline(cin, zip); 
r.set_zip(zip);

cout << "Phone#: ";
getline(cin, phone); 
r.set_phone(phone);

cout << "E-Mail: ";
getline(cin, email); 
r.set_email(email);
cout << endl;
}


static void editEntry(RolodexEntry& r) {
string c1 = "First Name", c2 = "Last Name",
       c3 = "Street", c4 = "Town", c5 = "State",
       c6 = "Phone", c7 = "Email", c8 = "Zip", c9 = "Return to Menu";

// print menu options
    cout << setw(5) << right << "1) " << c1 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "2) " << c2 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "3) " << c3 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "4) " << c4 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "5) " << c5 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "6) " << c6 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "7) " << c7 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "8) " << c8 << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << right << "9) " << c9 << endl;

    // receive user input
    string input;
    cout << "\n> ";
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << endl;
    string data;

    // menu options
    // get data
    // set data
    if(input == "1" || input == "F" || input == "f" || input == c1) {
        cout << "New First Name: ";
        getline(cin, data);
        r.set_fname(data);
    }//endif
    else if(input == "2" || input == "L" || input == "l" || input == c2){
        cout << "New Last Name: ";
        getline(cin, data);
        r.set_lname(data);
    }//endif
    else if(input == "3" || input == "Str" || input == "str" || input == c3){
        cout << "New Street: ";
        getline(cin, data);
        r.set_street(data);
    }//endif
    else if(input == "4" || input == "T" || input == "t" || input == c4){
        cout << "New Town: ";
        getline(cin, data);
        r.set_town(data);
    }//endif
    else if(input == "5" || input == "Sta" || input == "sta" || input == c5){
        cout << "New State: ";
        getline(cin, data);
        r.set_state(data);
    }//endif
    else if(input == "6" || input == "P" || input == "p" || input == c6){
        cout << "New Phone Number: ";
        getline(cin, data);
        r.set_phone(data);
    }//endif
    else if(input == "7" || input == "E" || input == "e" || input == c7){
        cout << "New E-Mail: ";
        getline(cin, data);
        r.set_email(data);
    }//endif
    else if(input == "8" || input == "Z" || input == "z" || input == c8){
        cout << "New Zip-Code: ";
        getline(cin, data);
        r.set_email(data);
    }//endif
    else if(input == "9" || input == "R" || input == "r" || input == c9)
        return;
    else
        cout << "Error: Invalid input." << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like your getCurrent check is giving you the exact opposite of what you want.

```
if(!myRolodex.getCurrent() != 0) { // make sure its not empty
```

Surely that should just be:

```
if(myRolodex.getCurrent() != 0) { // make sure its not empty
```

without the `!` at the front.

Comment: @g-makulik I think I just got lucky spotting that. :)